# Походження слова "миш'як"

Tags: вибір-слова, етимологія, росіянізм

З уроків хімії знала, що миш'як та арсен — це одна й та сама сполука. Нещодавно наткнулась на цікаву думку про походження слова *миш'як:*

"У наукових працях, словниках, популярних виданнях 40—80-х років XX ст. спостерігається паралельне функціонування хімічних термінів арсен і миш’як: Відомі багаті родовища руд таких металів, як арсен, стибій, кадмій, молібден, уран та ін. (з підр.); Газ, добутий випалюванням колчедану, містить деякі домішки, зокрема оксид миш’яку (з підр.).
Латинська назва arsenicum стала базовою для номінації хімічного елемента у термінологічних системах індоєвропейських мов: arsenis (англ.), arsen (нім.), arsenic (фран.), arsenico (ісп.), arszenik (польськ.), arzen (чеськ.), арсен, арсеник (болг.), арсеник (серб.). Термін *миш’як* відомий тільки у російській мові. Припускають, що ця назва походить від слова *мышь*, оскільки сполуки арсену використовували для знищення гризунів.
В українській науці до 30-х років XX століття послідовно послуговувалися терміном *арсен*. Однак він був витіснений у наступні десятиріччя російським запозиченням *миш’як*, яке, до речі, за своїми фонетичними особливостями суперечить закономірностям сполучуваності звуків, фонетиці української мови.
Упорядковуючи наукову термінологію відповідно до міжнародних термінологічних систем, фахівці рекомендують уживати назву хімічного елемента *арсен*, а не *миш’як*."

Напротивагу ствердженню автора, що миш'як  — це термін, запозичений з російської, знайшла ще одну [статтю](https://gazeta.ua/articles/events-journal/_nihto-u-sviti-ne-govorit-literaturnoyu-movoyu/470780), де сказано, що миш'як(мишак)  — термін українського походження.
[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=51203&page=1623) подає визначення слова *миш'як*, як те саме що *арсен*.

То ж чи не є *миш'як* русизмом? Яке походження цього слова? І чи не буде доцільнішим вживати в українській мові слово *арсен*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Щодо походження, то [Етимологічний словник](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf) (Т. 3, с. 471) подає таку інформацію:

> **миш'як** (хім.) «***арсен, тверда отруй­на речовина***», [мишак] «тс.», миш'яко­вистий; -р. мьішьяк, бр. мьіш’як, слн. misnica «тс.»; -*похідне утворення від мИша*; **назва зумовлена тим, що миш'яком отруюють мишей. або, мож­ливо, тим, що речовина має блискучо­сірий («мишиний») колір**; припускаєть­ся також (Брандт РФВ 23, 86) існування незасвідченого * мужьяк як кальки гр. cipaєvtx6v «миш'як», що помилково nо­в'язувалося з apGYJV «мужній».-Фас­мер ІІІ 28; Преобр. І 577.

Отже, лексема "миш’як" не є калькою з російської мови.

Щодо використання відповідника "арсен", то теж можна використовувати його, але ця назва не така розповсюджена. Як Ви вже писали, у СУМі "миш’як" = "арсен". Проте якщо задати одразу у пошуку [СУМ-8](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=169675&page=73) слово "арсен", вискакує стаття із визначенням, що є аналогічним до ЕСУМ:

> АРСЕ́Н, у, ч. Хімічний елемент з атомним номером 33, **тверда речовина сірого кольору** з металічним блиском, яка входить до складу деяких мінералів.
>
> Хлопець майже нічого не їв, і ніякі ліки, всі ті препарати арсену й заліза, що їх приписував йому Олександр Іванович, не допомагали (Б. Антоненко-Давидович).